# Как проверить, содержит ли строка определенное СЛОВО целиком в PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как проверить содержит ли строка определенное слово?

Есть код:

```
if(strpos('Получились отличные спагетти', 'спа') !== false){
    echo "ДА";
} else{
    echo "НЕТ";
}
```

Нужно чтобы было "НЕТ", но в результате получается "ДА".

Comment: можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями или превратить строку в список слов и проверять в нем

Comment: список слов не подходит, это 1 предложение из 1000 только, а без регулярных выражений не обойтись?

Comment: а почему список слов не подходит, если вы не хотите регулярки использовать? делите по пробелам  при помощи explode(),  подчищайте знаки препинания при помощи trim(). получатся чистые слова, проверяйте на наличие нужного слова в списке

Comment: Потому что, в некоторых случаях нужно по 2-3 слова сразу выбирать. Например нужно будет: "отличные спагетти", а они будут ни в одном предложении.

Comment: о! да вы, матушка, скрываете большую часть задачи, похоже. Может стоит почетче сформулировать, то  что вам надо. приведенный в вопросе код даже не пытается искать словосочетания, или слова в разных предложениях

Comment: Извините, тут надо было весь код и задачу опубликовать? :) Смысл следующий: есть переменная $name, в ней 1000 предложений, нужно сделать, если встречается слово "спа" вернуть положительный результат, но я натыкаюсь на проблему как например "спагетти", разумеется помимо "спа", нужно будет и другие словосочетания вытащить.

Comment: @СветланаЗайцева регулярка, как вам уже сказали, поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = 'Получились отличные спагетти';
$word = 'спа';

if (preg_match("/\b$word\b/u", $string)) {
    echo "ДА";
} else{
    echo "НЕТ";
}
```

При `$word = 'спа';` выдаст "НЕТ", при `$word = 'спагетти';` выдаст "ДА".  Теперь вместо `$string` подставляем нужную строку, а вместо `$word` - то, что пытаемся найти в строке

---

`\b` - в регулярках означает "Граница слова"

Comment: `$string = 'Получились отличные спагетти, теперь можно в спа, а то вечером опаздаю на пилатес и ийогу.';

if (preg_match("/\bспа\b/u", $string)) {echo "спа - ДА";} 
if (preg_match("/\bпилатес\b/u", $string)) {echo "пилатес - ДА";} 
if (preg_match("/\bийогу\b/u", $string)) {echo "ийога - ДА";}
if (preg_match("/\bфитнес\b/u", $string)) {echo "фитнес - ДА";} 
if (preg_match("/\bресторан\b/u", $string)) {echo "ресторан - ДА";}`

Comment: Хорошо, смотрите что у меня получилось :) Я обречена на такой долгий код? или можно как то по умному всё сократить? Задача вывести определённые слова из $string.

Comment: @СветланаЗайцева можно в цикле прогнать все слова, например, сложив их в предварительно массив.....а также в регулярках есть возможность делать `OR` если нужно именно его применить..... вариантов много. Но это вопрос оптимизации данной лапши, которая никак  к текущему вопросу уже не относится

Comment: Вот поэтому я и не хотела связываться с регулярками, думала в php предусмотрена специальная функция типа str_contains, чтобы из огромного текста, который будет периодически пополняться вытащить топ слов с точным вхождением...

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за альтернативное решение задачи ;)

Comment: @СветланаЗайцева я не знаю вашей всей задачи, совершенно не понимаю, что такое "топ слов". Но как я уже написал, в регулярках есть логическое ИЛИ и И. Их можно использовать. Сделать маленькую функцию для этого не представляется сложным. И уже эту функцию использовать....... в итоге можно будет делать просто `if (checkStr($text, $arrayOfWords)) { ... }` и никаких проблем